Android NDK traffic forwarding
I am trying to develop an as-multiplatform-as-possible app in rust that would include network traffic forwarding through a special tunnel network interface. For most of the platforms it seems to be clear: there is a C++ tunnel interface provider class in iOS API, MacOS has tunnel and firewall APIs (also in C++), there are a wintun library and a built-in firewall for Windows, Linux uses TUN interfaces and iptables firewall.
However, when it comes to Android, things are not that clear: as far as I understood, the only way for both tunnel interface creation and traffic routing is VPNService API for java and kotlin.
Is there really absolutely no way to create a tunnel interface and setup traffic forwarding rules for Android with NDK (and with my rust app)? Have I missed something?
Maybe, it would be better to create platform-specific services for all mobile platforms (since both iOS and Android use special SDK classes to manipulate tunnels and traffic forwarding instead of libraries) and pass only tunnel file descriptors (for data reading and writing) to rust?
I would be grateful for any links and advices!
